# Get file depth in directory tree

Tags: bash, directory, centos, freebsd, depth

I'm using command `find` to recursively browse through directory tree, counting files, sizes, etc...

Now I need to get directory depth of each file.
Is there any portable way for both *FreeBSD* and *CentOS*?

I know that `find` is able to prinf actual directory depth but sadly this works only on CentOS, not FreeBSD.

Additionaly - I need to keep standard `find` output OR put directory depth on the beginning of output and cut it from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can count the `/` in path :

```
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo '{}' | grep -o / | wc -l' \;
```

Or with file names :

```
$ mkdir -p one/two/three four/five && touch file one/two/file one/two/three/file
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo -n '{}' :; echo '{}' | grep -o / | wc -l' \;
./file :1
./one/two/file :3
./one/two/three/file :4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`find . -type d -exec bash -c 'echo $(tr -cd / <<< "$1"|wc -c):$1' -- {} \;  | sort -n | tail -n 1 | awk -F: '{print $1, $2}'`